# I want to remove "Overwrite existing files" check from rteUploadDialog.aspx in sharepoint 2010

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, javascript

I need to uncheck the "Overwrite existing files" check that comes by default on the rteUploadDialog.aspx page (while adding file to a rich text box in OOTB lists). How can it be achieved? If I modify the page from the /_layouts folder then it gives page not found error after that. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Anurag U.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a JavaScript/JQuery to the master page which can detect the current page based on the URL and hide the check box displayed in the page.